# How do I customise controller actions in Laravel Jetstream?

Tags: php, laravel, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I would like to add some data for the Create vue file for the teams feature in Laravel Jetstream, but I haven't seen a way how to publish the vendor controllers. Essentially what I am trying to do is, add the ability on the team creation page to specify a different owner to the team you are currently creating, rather than it just defaulting to the current user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jetstream implements a pattern that uses Actions, instead of publishing routes and controllers.

You can customize the Action that creates a Team in your `app/Actions/Jetstream/CreateTeam.php` file.

The Action files should be published with the installation of Jetstream.

Comment: I understand that, but that action is completed after I submit the teams create form, I need to add data via props to the create form before submitting so I can populate a dropdown with data.

Comment: You can just edit `resources/js/Pages/Teams/Partials/CreateTeamForm.vue` to add any data to your form before submitting.